# json converted into php array then display correctly as list

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've got my json, I've converted it into a php array, here's the print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 187
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 209
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 210
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 211
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 188
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 196
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 197
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 198
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 189
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 193
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 202
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 190
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 191
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 206
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 192
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 203
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 204
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 205
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 207
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 208
                        )

                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 194
        )

)
```

I want to now convert that array into a list that I can eventually update a db. But I can't work out how to do the children arrays:

So far I've got:

```
$arrayList = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['nestable-output']), true);

foreach ($arrayList as $array1){
    foreach ($array1 as $pageID => $pageOrder){
        echo $pageID . "-" . $pageOrder . "<br/>";
        //foreach ($pageOrder as $pageID2 => $pageOrder2){
        //  echo $pageID2 . "-" . $pageOrder2 . "<br/>";
        //}
    }
}
```

I know the commented part is incorrect as it gives me an 'Invalid argument supplied' but can anyone tell me what the right methodology here is please?

Here's my current output without the commented part:

```
id-187
id-209
children-Array
id-188
children-Array
id-189
children-Array
id-202
children-Array
id-203
children-Array
id-194
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to loop through each, whether the id is `id` or `children`. Since the value when the key is `id` is a number, not an array, it will fail when trying to run as a foreach. Instead, only loop when you KNOW it's an array (the strcmp comes into play):

```
$arrayList = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['nestable-output']), true);

foreach ($arrayList as $array1){
    foreach ($array1 as $pageID => $pageOrder){
        echo $pageID . "-" . $pageOrder . "<br/>";
        if(strcmp("children", $pageID) == 0)) {
            foreach ($pageOrder as $pageID2 => $pageOrder2){
              echo $pageID2 . "-" . $pageOrder2 . "<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to add another foreach in the middle to display the final level of the array, but it's working now. Sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees!

Comment: @jimbeeer it's a simple mistake, I bet you won't make it again now

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an "invalid argument" error because you are trying to pass the ID value (which is an integer) to your second `foreach` construct.

Try modifying your code to read:

```
$arrayList = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['nestable-output']), true);

foreach ($arrayList as $array1){
    foreach ($array1 as $pageID => $pageOrder){
        echo $pageID . "-" . $pageOrder . "<br/>";
        if($pageID == 'children') {
            foreach ($pageOrder as $pageID2 => $pageOrder2){
              echo $pageID2 . "-" . $pageOrder2 . "<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting a `$pageID => $pageOrder` from the `foreach($array1...)`. You're getting a `$key => $value`. Your $key could be equal to the string 'id', in which case the $value would be the id number from the array. Your $key could also be equal to the string 'children', in which case the $value would be your array of child ids.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are looking to get a string out of a multi-dimensional array. Try something like this:

```
$arrayList = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['nestable-output']), true);

$list = trim(array_walk($arrayList, 'get_ids'), ',');

function get_ids($array_list) {
    $list = '';

    foreach($array_list as $key => $value) {
        if('children' == $key) $list .= get_ids($value)
        else {
            foreach($value as $index => $id) $list .= $id . ', ';
        }
    }

    return $list;
}
```

Note that this should work even if you have arrays more than 2 levels deep.